# LaTeX to .docx using Pandoc – issues with itemizing

Tags: enumerate, itemize, pandoc

I generated two kinds of output files from my .tex file.

The .pdf output (which has correct formatting):
[image]

The .docx output using Pandoc (which incorrectly itemizes "test c-2" as item "d."):
[image]

How should I prevent this kind of incorrect itemization?

My .tex code (to be complied with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=1in,
  inner=0.6in,
  outer=0.7in,
  bottom=1in,
  headheight=2ex,
  headsep=2ex
}
\usepackage{fontspec}   
%\usepackage{xeCJK}       
%\setCJKmainfont{DFKai-SB} 
%\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"             
%\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt    
%\setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold=3]{DFKai-SB} 

\input epsf      

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `basename #1 .tif`.png}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.7em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thepage} {\arabic{page}}

\newpage

\noindent


\begin{enumerate}
\item test
$$
\mathbf{P}=1
$$
\begin{enumerate}
\item test a

\item test b-1

test b-2
\item test c-1
$$
\mathbf{E}=1
$$
test c-2
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1.5cm}
\footnotesize

\clearpage 
\end{document}
```

My Pandoc code:

```
pandoc -s input.tex -o output.docx
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in Pandoc. A smaller MWE that also displays the issue: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\[
\mathbf{P}=1
\]
extra line after equation
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
`

Comment: Not sure if export to ODT could have some drawback for a Word user, but at least the Marijn's MWE is well exported to this format.

Comment: @Fran Exporting to ODT also has issues with itemizing when dealing with a more complex numeration structure.

Comment: @isend  Any export always pays a toll, even from Markdown to anything else (i.e., from  simplest to complex) that is a trip relatively comfortable, but between other formats will be always a pain directly proportional to the complexity of the formats, with LaTeX to Word at the top of the masochistic scale.  You will be very lucky if you will have issues only with complex list.